# Itextsharp Generate arabic font

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have a solution that contains ASP WEB API projects

i have a methode that use ItextSharp to create a PDF DOCUMENT
this document contains french and arabic text
I use this code to get arabic font:

```
    public static BaseFont GetArabicFont()
    {

        var appDomain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var basePath = appDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var fontPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "fonts", "pdf", "ARIALUNI.TTF");

        try
        {
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            return bf;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        }
   }
```

when I execute the application I can generate the pdf document correctly (including french and arabic text)
after deploying web api project in IIS 7 when i call the method that generate a pdf, but no response
when I use Postmane to call the api directly I see this message:
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": Identity-H is not a supported encoding name"

I do not know if the problem is IN IIS or I must change IDENTITY_H font ?
can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

If you use `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`, iText will *always* embed a font. If it didn't, iText would create PDFs that aren't compliant with ISO-32000-1. It's more correct to to this:

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

This isn't really important, as iText will ignore your error and embed the font anyway, even if you tell iText not to embed it. That is why your code works correctly on your machine.

You say that the same code doesn't work on IIS. I am assuming that the `fontPath` to `ARIALUNI.TTF` doesn't result in a font on IIS. Maybe the font is missing; maybe IIS doesn't have access to that font. In that case, an error is thrown and the following line is encountered:

```
return BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

This line doesn't make sense either, as `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` can't be used in combination with `BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN`. Moreover: Times-Roman doesn't contain any Arabic glyphs, abd you can't embed Times-Roman unless you provide the PFB file along with the AFM file.

The solution to your problem is to make sure that `ArialUni.ttf` is present on your server, or that you provide another font that supports Arabic.

Comment: after verification the problem is that ArialUni.ttf was not present on the server when I added it the PDF was generated corerctelly